# jQuery: remove element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem that I'm trying to solve, the current way of doing it requires that I remove elements.

```
<div id="toremove">
    // some JavaScript here
</div>
```

So I have a function that does something nice, then when that finishes I'd like it to remove the `"toremove"` element. I have looked at the jQuery documentation, similar posts allover the Internet but nothing seems to work.

Here's what I'm doing and have tried:

```
$("#toremove") = $()
$("#toremove").empty();
$("#toremove").remove();
```

Nothing seems to work for me, any help is appreciated.

Comment: `$('#toremove').remove()` is correct.  If that doesn't work, you have another problem.

Comment: did you write `$("#toremove").remove();` in `onDomReady` i.e. in something like : `$(function(){...});`

Comment: Make sure you have only one item with that ID... weird things can happen if not

Comment: It worked when I used '#toremove' instead of "#toremove" but the js I had inside that div still executes for some magical reason.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`$('#toremove').remove();` should do what you need. Are you sure there isn't a problem elsewhere in your code?

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6yox74rx/1/)

Comment: This worked, but my problem is that the <js> I had in that div still executes.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are removing the `div` when its not even created.

do something like this :

```
$(function(){
    $("#id").remove();
});
```

This will make sure the DOM is ready.

Also see to it that your id is **unique**!

Answer (score 3):

You can do other of the way to deal with this issue, I will show you I know as following.( please pick anyone up you like)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="toremove">
        ...some javascript here....
    </div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#toremove').html('');  // option 1
    $('#toremove').attr('style', 'display:none')  // option 2
    $('#toremove').attr('style', 'visibility:hidden') // option 3
    $('#toremove').remove();  // option 4
    $('#toremove').hide();   // option 5
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$("#id").remove();` should work.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltwxxxao/)

Problems you might have with your code:

Maybe you aren't using the `$(function() { });` around your code which tells jquery to wait until all html elements are loaded. ( short form for `$(document).ready(function() { })` );

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<div id="toremove">
    ...some javascript here....
</div>
```

Corresponding jQuery:

```
$("#toremove").click(function() {
    $("#toremove").remove();
});
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/86z93dzk/ (notice that the JS is loaded `onDomready`)

Thus, in your case, you could put the jQuery code anywhere and wrap it with `$(document).ready`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toremove").click(function() {
        $("#toremove").remove();
    });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS: it's much simpler, and works even for dynamic elements (JSP, etc.). One bad thing: the no-displayed element still exists in the page source.

```
<style>
 #toremove {
  display: none;
 }
</style>
```